# Ansible Dynamic Inventory fails to get the latest ec2 information

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-inventory

I am using `ec2.py` dynamic inventory for provisioning with ansible. 
I have placed the `ec2.py` in `/etc/ansible/hosts` file and marked it executable. 
I also have the `ec2.ini` file in `/etc/ansible/hosts`.

```
[ec2]

regions = us-west-2
regions_exclude = us-gov-west-1,cn-north-1


destination_variable = public_dns_name

vpc_destination_variable = ip_address
route53 = False

all_instances = True
all_rds_instances = False


cache_path = ~/.ansible/tmp

cache_max_age = 0

nested_groups = False
group_by_instance_id = True
group_by_region = True
group_by_availability_zone = True
group_by_ami_id = True
group_by_instance_type = True
group_by_key_pair = True
group_by_vpc_id = True
group_by_security_group = True
group_by_tag_keys = True
group_by_tag_none = True
group_by_route53_names = True
group_by_rds_engine = True
group_by_rds_parameter_group = True
```

Above is my `ec2.ini` file

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: yes
  vars_files:
   - ../group_vars/dev_vpc
   - ../group_vars/dev_sg
   - ../hosts_vars/ec2_info
  vars:
    instance_type: t2.micro
  tasks:
   - name: Provisioning EC2 instance
     local_action:
     module: ec2
     region: "{{ region }}"
     key_name: "{{ key }}"
     instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
     image: "{{ ami_id }}"
     wait: yes
     group_id: ["{{ sg_npm }}", "{{sg_ssh}}"]
     vpc_subnet_id: "{{ PublicSubnet }}"
     source_dest_check: false
     instance_tags: '{"Name": "EC2", "Environment": "Development"}'
 register: ec2
  - name: associate new EIP for the instance
    local_action:
      module: ec2_eip
      region: "{{ region }}"
      instance_id: "{{ item.id }}"
      with_items: ec2.instances
  - name: Waiting for NPM Server to come-up
    local_action:
      module: wait_for
      host: "{{ ec2 }}"
      state: started
      delay: 5
      timeout: 200
 - include: ec2-configure.yml
```

Now the configuring script is as follows

```
- name: Configure EC2 server
  hosts: tag_Name_EC2
  user: ec2-user
  sudo: True
  gather_facts: True
  tasks:
   - name: Install nodejs related packages
     yum: name={{ item }} enablerepo=epel state=present
     with_items:
      - nodejs
      - npm
```

However when the configure script is called, the second script results into no hosts found. 
If I execute the `ec2-configure.yml` just alone and if the EC2 server is up & running then it is able to find it and configure it.

I added the `wait_for` to make sure that the instance is in running state before the `ec2-configure.yml` is called.

Would appreciate if anyone can point my error. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After researching I came to know that the dynamic inventory doesnt refresh between playbook calls, it will only refresh if you are executing the playbook seprately.
However I was able to resolve the issue by using `add_host` command.

```
- name: Add  Server to inventory
  local_action: add_host hostname={{ item.public_ip }} groupname=webserver
  with_items: webserver.instances
```

Answer (score 2):

With ansible 2.0+, you refresh the dynamic inventory in the middle of the playbook as the task like this:

```
- meta: refresh_inventory
```

To extend this a bit, If you are getting problem with the cache in your playbook, then you can use it like this:

```
   - name: Refresh the ec2.py cache
     shell: "./inventory/ec2.py --refresh-cache"
     changed_when: no

   - name: Refresh inventory
     meta: refresh_inventory
```

where `./inventory` is the path to your dynamic inventory, please adjust it accordingly.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

`Configure EC2 server` play can't find any hosts from EC2 dynamic inventory because the new instance was added in the first play of the playbook - during the same execution. Group `tag_Name_EC2` didn't exist in the inventory when the inventory was read and thus can't be found.

When you run the same playbook again `Configure EC2 server` should find the group.

We have used the following workaround to guide users in this kind of situations.

First, provision the instance:

```
tasks:
  - name: Provisioning EC2 instance
    local_action:
    module: ec2
    ...
    register: ec2
```

Then add a new play before `ec2-configure.yml`. The play uses `ec2` variable that was registered in `Provisioning EC2 instance` and will fail and exit the playbook if any instances were launched:

```
- name: Stop and request a re-run if any instances were launched
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Stop if instances were launched
      fail: msg="Re-run the playbook to load group variables from EC2 dynamic inventory for the just launched instances!"
      when: ec2.changed

- include: ec2-configure.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also refresh the cache:

`ec2.py --refresh-cache`

Or if your using as the Ansible host file:

`/etc/ansible/hosts --refresh-cache`